# Problem in form auto submit

Tags: php, javascript

How do i submit my form when the timer goes and also if refresh is clicked.??
The problem i faced is whenever refreshed it is asking for user confirmation, if clicked cancel, it remains on same page.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably arriving at that page via `method="post"`. The browser will not re-submit that without permission from the user.

So instead you have two options:

1. Use `method="get"`
2. After the post, have the server redirect to a regular page, not a page that is the result of a post.